# How to concat values which retrieved from database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-group-concat

I am executing this query in SQL Server 2008

```
 SELECT (CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

and it shows the result `2013-07-22`.

I need to print this result as `22713`, where 22 is the date 7 is the month 13 is the year.

How could I do this?

Comment: Displayed how?  Desktop, browser, tablet, phone, language....?

Comment: Operations with string isn't what SQL is best at. More good practice use other tools (Java, Python, C#, etc)

Comment: till now I didn't do nothing, i do not have such any idea how to do this

Comment: @duffymo in browser using asp.net C#

Comment: It's a rendering issue.  Let the technology that's doing display format it appropriately.  Get it from the database as a Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(dd,GETDATE()) as varchar(10))
  +CAST(DATEPART(mm,GETDATE()) as varchar(10))
  +RIGHT(CAST(DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()) as varchar(10)),2)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/17601)

Answer (score 1):

1) It bad practice use SQL for string operation. More right external tools
2) I use other RDBMS. Below query work with it:

```
select (extract(day from ua.stamp))||(extract(month from
ua.stamp))||(extract(year from ua.stamp)) from useractions ua
```

Furthemote, this link can help you:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/55d23bb0-6e1e-4a03-9bed-94e7c755ec4d/get-the-day-from-date-value-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You could read the string, go over it with a tokenizer, split it and put it back together the way you want it to be. What language are you using?